# Create an NSMutableArray of NSRange's and properly read the range values later

Tags: ios, nsregularexpression, nsrange, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to create an `NSMutableArray` of the ranges discovered from `NSRegularExpression`, but I cannot get the `NSMutableArray` to hold objects. Help?

Declare the array by: `NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

At the end of my regular expression loops:

```
for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in minedMatches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [aMatch range];
    [matches addObject: [NSValue valueWithRange:matchRange]];
}
```

In another part of my code, I have the a for loop wanting to use `matches`; however, it is not full:

```
if (matches != nil) {
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.count; i++) {
                [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: minedColor range:[[matches objectAtIndex:i]rangeValue]]; 
            }
        }
```

**Note:

`minedColor`, `minedMatches` and `attributedString` are declared properly throughout my code. I am using `addAttribute` in a separate location because I need to only change the color of the text in between sections of key words such as "Go" and "end".

**Edit 1 (request for entire method)

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

self.notepadTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:20]; //custom font
UIFont *normalFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:20];//fail-safe font for attributed string
NSString *textEntryContents = [[self notepadTextView ]text]; //declares user inputted string
[gCore processSpeechText:textEntryContents]; //internal processing
NSMutableArray *mined = [gCore getHighLightContainer]; //array with strings that need to be colored
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textEntryContents
                                                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: normalFont}]; //initialize attributed string
matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //initialize matches
UIColor *minedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(126.0/255.0) green:(204.0/255.0) blue:(136.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; //initialize color for attributed string

BOOL colorChangeDidRun = '\0'; //initialize if color was changed

if ([gCore dataMiningInProgress] == YES) { //if it is the start of a section
    colorChangeDidRun = NO; 
    if (mined != nil){ //fail-safe
        for (int i = 0; i < mined.count; i++){
            NSError *regexErrorMined;
            NSRegularExpression *regexMined = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mined[i]]
                                                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexErrorMined];
            if (!regexErrorMined) {
                NSArray *minedMatches = [regexMined matchesInString:[attributedString string]
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [[attributedString string] length])];
                for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in minedMatches) {
                    NSRange matchRange = [aMatch range];
                    [matches addObject: [NSValue valueWithRange:matchRange]]; //add range values to matches array                     
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
else if ([gCore dataMiningInProgress] == NO) { //if end of section
    if (colorChangeDidRun == NO) { //if the color change has not happened yet
        if (matches != nil) {
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.count; i++) {
                colorChangeDidRun = YES; //prevent color change in unnecessary spots
                [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: minedColor range:[[matches objectAtIndex:i]rangeValue]];            
            }
        }
    }
}

self.notepadTextView.attributedText = attributedString; //output attributed string
```

}

I did not post the entire method originally because it requires a lot of explaining, as I'm sure you can see. Basically, the user will input text into a text view. That text is then data mined **if** the words fall between "Start" and "end". These key words signal triggers that change the value of `[gCore dataMiningInProgress]`, which is a global object.

Currently, if a user were to type "Start the cat is outside end", the words "cat" and "outside" will change color when the user inputs "end". If the user inputs more string such as: "Start the cat is now inside end", the word "cat" will automatically turn green even before the user types "end". I want to prevent this from happening. I only want the color to change during the individual sections of "start......end"

**All outside variables are in working order, the only thing I cannot get thus far is the `addAttribute` from the array of ranges in `matches` because although it does not say it is `nil`, `matches.count` is 0 in the `else if()` conditional.**

Comment: Define "is not full". And is `matches` a local variable or an instance variable?

Comment: And have you verified you are actually getting valid matchRange when adding? Put a debug breakpoint on [matches addObject:] and look to see if the object count goes up one immediately after

Comment: Also, are you sure that the for loop in you're first example code actually runs, and objects are added to the matches array?

Comment: Couldn't `minedMatches` be used or just copied?

Comment: "cannot get the NSMutableArray to hold objects" is not an adequate description of a problem.  You have not identified a specific problem, and certainly not adequately characterized one.

Comment: If I add an `NSLog` in the first code example to see matches.count, it in fact log the proper number of objects. That being said, if I were to add the same `NSLog` to the code right before `addAttribute`, the count is logged as 0. @LyricalPanda @timgcarlson

Comment: That's probably because `matches` is nil.

Comment: @rmaddy, currently `matches` is declared inside of a method `-(void)textViewDidChange` along with the rest of the `NSRegularExpression` loops and code. I have tried making `matches` a property of the class, and writing to that, but I could not get that to work either.

Comment: Using a local variable will never work because it can't be used in other methods. Use a private property or an instance variable.

Comment: the code pieces in the post look correct. Could you list complete `-textViewDidChange` method implementation?

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear, but the `addAttributes` part of the code is in the same method as the declaration of `matches` and the `NSRegualrExpression` code, therefore I thought the local variable would work? @rmaddy

Comment: No, it was not clear at all that both chunks of code and the declaration of `matches` are in the same scope. Please update your question to show the complete scope showing how `matches` is initialized and all of the places it is used. And you still have not told us what the actual problem is. Is `matches` `nil`? If not, does it have any objects in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using suggestions from @kambala and @LyricalPanda, my original problem of `matches` being `nil` in the `else` statement was solved through a scoping issue. Although I created a property in the header file for `matches` and `@synthesize`'d it, my `NSMutableArray` was not being written to on a class-level scale. I changed the scope to create a global variable for `matches` that can now be accessed from any file. Seems like a waste of some coding power, but that was how I was able to get the `MutableArray` to hold objects outside of one instance. Using the `@extern` command, allows successful reading and writing of the array full of ranges.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very basic mistake here: it's not possible to execute both branches of `if` and `else if` in one pass. So if `[gCore dataMiningInProgress] == YES` then only `matches` will be filled with objects, and that's all. If the condition is `NO`, then `matches` is an empty array (because it wasn't filled with objects obviously).

P.S. It's no use writing `if ([gCore dataMiningInProgress] == YES) ... else if ([gCore dataMiningInProgress] == NO)` because if it doesn't evaluate to `YES`, then it's definitely `NO` :) So it's just an `if-else` construction.

Comment: I didn't even think of the `if-else` minor detail, so thank you for that! What would be your advice about either how to access `matches` in the `else` section without it being an empty array? I tried to declare `matches` in my .h file and then synthesizing it, but that didn't work either :/

Comment: @momodude22 This really depends on the flow of your code. Did you want matches to persist with each textDidChange? Then add it as a property and initialize the array in viewDidLoad & removeAllObjects on when you  exit out of the textView. If you didn't want it to persist, then drop the if/else.

Comment: I have changed the color of the words successfully without the `if-else` stuff, but the problem here is that the initial color change occurs once the user typed "end". If they were to start a new section after that by typing "Start" the color change will occur as the user types in real time BEFORE they type "end" if that word was typed in the previous section. I don't want it to automatically change color if it has been seen before, I would like it to change colors only once the user types "end", which is why I believed the `if-else` statements were needed @LyricalPanda

Comment: @momodude22 then save your array of ranges in a property and apply coloring only after "end" is typed (check last characters of textview's text or whatever)